R language except_warning()
I run expect_warning(f(1), NA) there is nothing happens, but expect_warning(f(1)) would raise an error. What does NA do here? Is NA means that expect_warning(f(1), NA) doesn't care if an error occurs here?
expect_warning(f(1), NA) #return nothing
expect_warning(f(1)) #error raised


This is explained in help("expect_warning").
